# seeding table not sucess in Laravel 7 and Laratrust 6

Tags: php, laravel-7, laratrust

using Laravel 7 and Laratrust 6 and need seeding the Table using the seed command but seeding only some tables only. not seeding following tables as well in the database `users,role_user,permission_user`
my DataBaseSeeder.php

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
   public function run()
    {
        
        $this->call(LaratrustSeeder::class); 
        }
}
```

how could I fix this problem?

Comment: are you getting any error or you are just not having certain tables seeded?

Answer (score 0):

add -> namespace Database\Seeders; in LaratrustSeeder.php in seeder folder

Comment: please detail your answer